# Recording Issue with OBS Studio software, each video recording is not in sync with the audio for the recording

Tags: windows-10, video, recording, obs-studio

I use OBS Studio to record video's usually of podcasts that I want to keep. Each time I record OBS creates 2 identical recordings when I only need one, so I just delete the second one. When I playback any video recording the speed of the video does not keep up with the associated audio of the video but it is clear and fine. Unfortunately OBS does not have a live chat or support service for any users experiencing problems to contact. So if you can't work out any problem by trial and error you are left high and dry. I really need to find someone who really knows OBS Studio very well. I would appreciate any assistance or recommendations.

Many Thanks

Brett

Answer (score 0):

As far as your audio sync goes, it sounds like you need to add a sync offset. This is very easy to set, simply go to the audio mixer and click the gear icon. Then click on "Advanced Audio Properties". Here you'll find the sync offset for each audio channel.

[Advanced Audio Properties dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCpLs.png)

Set the sync offset in milliseconds forward or back until your audio is synced. For any production movie or video they will use a [clapperboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapperboard) to sync up the audio, you can probably make do with just clapping your hands.

As for the two video files created, the only time I've heard of that happening is when you accidentally have two instances of OBS running. Check to make sure there is only 1 process for OBS running while recording, also check that your output and recording settings are correct. If you still have problems, try re-installing OBS.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem all of a sudden when things had worked perfectly prior to that.  You can see some of the symptoms and answer here.

## Try changing this Windows 10 setting

This was caused by a setting in Windows 10.

There's an option to display HD for certain games which was on and I had to switch it off.

To get to the setting right click your desktop and click on "display settings" or else go to the Windows 10 home/start menu and click on the cog (settings) and find "display".

Under the heading "Windows HD Colour"

Switch off "Use HDR"

This also stopped the delay in recording!

**Read the full question/comments**

[Recorded videos colours are really bright. But only on some software](https://superuser.com/questions/1650176/recorded-videos-colours-are-really-bright-but-only-on-some-software)