# Recorded videos colours are really bright. But only on some software

Tags: video, graphics-card, display, video-streaming, obs-studio

Ever since I got a new computer and a new monitor my colours are really bright when recording my screen.  Since I'm a designer it makes me look like I've designed some weird designs and the clients often feedback on it.

This occurs with OBS Studio, but also with Microsoft Teams.  But it doesn't seem to occur with some other software like ActivePresenter.  ActivePresenter actually exports the video at the end whereas the others seem to record it on the fly.

OBS also has a delay in recording the screen until I click on it for some reason.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to solve this issue?

I've tried using the best possible wire for the screen connection but that didn't help.  I've also updated all the graphics card and windows drivers.

## How screenshots see it

Check the green button out  here:
[image: green button]

And the front end here:
[image: Front end]

## How recorded video or streamed video sees it

Then see how it records on this video.  The colours go a lot brighter, particularly on anything blue.

https://youtu.be/S-u5HPqujPY

Comment: Something, somewhere, is using the wrong profile. Though unless your display is calibrated & profiled, you have no known start-point anyway.

Comment: I have plugged it in and not done anything else.  So yes, you are correct I have no known start point.  What would you suggest are the next actions?

Comment: tbh, I'm pretty good on colour workflow, but I don't know OBS at all, so I can't do specifics. If you want actually accurate you need to start with a hardware colorimeter to properly calibrate & profile the screen. Most capture/photography apps will then automatically work with that when converting to your destination profile, be it sRGB or Rec 709. There's a quick overview here that looks OK, though it's probably overkill for screen-cap in OBS it should give you a start - https://jonnyelwyn.co.uk/film-and-video-editing/colour-management-for-video-editors/

Comment: Colorimeters start at about $£€70 for something like a Huey Pro, but they don't get good for another 150 or so - i1Display or Spyder 5 etc. [Huey no longer works on Mac, but afaik still does on Win10] If this is for business, I'd seriously consider the i1 - If the data leaves you in perfect colour, then you can blame the client ;)) Also - ensure the profile is actually **embedded** in your work, some browsers [Chrome, Firefox] have very very bad default settings if they don't find a profile.

Comment: So I just tried with ActivePresenter and it works fine.  So the problem is with OBS rather than my monitor or any profile set up isn't it?

Comment: If it looks the same to you as recorded, then it's using the correct profile - conversely, if it's not… it's not. [neither, btw, is a known quantity unless you're calibrated, it merely means the same is being used for both] I have to defer to more experienced OBS users as to how to fix that. I do wish you luck. it does sound like a mis-config somwehere, but idk where to look, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a **setting in Windows 10**.

There's an option to display HD for certain games which was on and I had to switch it off.

To get to the setting right click your desktop and click on **"display settings"** or else go to the Windows 10 home/start menu and click on the cog (settings) and find "display".

Under the heading **"Windows HD Colour"**

**Switch off "Use HDR"**

This also stopped the delay in recording!

[image: Windows 10 Display Settings]

Comment: Ahh… HDR. The worst thing ever devised, as you've just discovered. It throws away any attempt at accuracy in exchange for some kind of guesswork, "better" image. I'm glad you found it. It hadn't occurred to me at all. It's one I switch off on everything from TVs to computer displays, but it's always an 'off & forget it ever existed' action ;)

Comment: Good man, thank you for the advice, I'll follow it.